# No modules named 'tensorflow.compat.v2' on Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following this https://thebinarynotes.com/how-to-train-mask-r-cnn-on-the-custom-dataset/ tutorial of Mask RCNN, and trying execute it on Google Colab.

Versions of Tensorflow and Keras are mentioned below: tensorflow==1.13.1 keras==2.1.0

3 weeks ago I have already used this code and trained the model on my custom dataset successfully, and predicted the results as well.

But now, when I try to execute the same code in same environment I got the following error. Tried multiple solutions, like updating Tensorflow to 2.x, but the code is not compatible with it, and creates other issues.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP5KV.png)

Comment: What is the current version of tensorflow in your google colab environment ? Google colab may have upgraded their tensorflow version. Did you try uninstalling the default tensorflow version and install the version mentioned by you (i.e) `tensorflow==1.13.1 keras==2.1.0` ?

Comment: Please only post questions only once, I did see a exact duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67818806/no-module-named-tensorflow-compat-v2-on-colab

Answer (score 1):

The `tf.compat.v2` module was added in `1.14`. Upgrade to `1.14` , `1.15`, or `2.0` and this will work fine.

`tensorflow.compat.v2` worked for me on Tensorflow==1.15

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.15
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from
*import keras*
into
*import tensorflow.keras*

**Example to import TimeseriesGenerator from keras**

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
```

Credit to [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘tensorflow.compat.v2‘解决方法](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_38282306/article/details/117745378)