# Difficulty updating keras/tensorflow on mac

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.7

I am working on a jupyter notebook script which I used last year to train a neural network.

When I try to import the keras tokenizer:

`from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer`

I receive this error

[image: :]

I have seen other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67819062/no-modules-named-tensorflow-compat-v2-on-colab) which suggest that I need to update tensorflow. My anaconda environment tells me I have 1.13.1 installed. But when I try to update tensorflow-base to 1.15 in the anaconda navigator, I receive this error:

[image]

I can update tensorflow from my command line using:

`conda install tensorflow=1.15.0`

But this doesn't update tensorflow in my anaconda environment and the error persists in my notebook.

Any help would be much appreciated! As you can probably tell, I am a novice python user.

Answer (score 0):

The error says some packages needed to update Tensorflow/Andaconda requires Python 3.11 or newer. Since not all of the error log can be seen however, I would upgrade to python 3.7 to be safe. You can download this from the official page: https://www.python.org/downloads/

If the problem persists, try using pip to update the packages(In bash) :

```bash
pip install tensorflow
pip install conda
```

If you get an error while using pip, try:

```bash
pip3 install tensorflow
pip3 install conda
```

This same method can be used to update keras:

```bash
pip install keras
```

or if that does not work:

```bash
pip3 install keras
```

If pip is not recognized at a command, Python 3.7 is not added to path. I do not have experience with macOS, but this article should go into enough depth.
https://realpython.com/add-python-to-path/#how-to-add-python-to-path-on-linux-and-macos